# How to add background text to video recording?

Tags: reactjs, video.js

I'm using videojs-record. On the top right corner there is `REC` text along with a red dot.[image]

I am thinking to add more text to the ongoing video recording, something like video logs that Matt Damon did in the movie Martian.[image]. Anyone knows how to achieve that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The [record indicator is just a `<div>` element](https://github.com/collab-project/videojs-record/blob/master/src/js/controls/record-indicator.js) and won't be stored in the recorded video.

However, by the same logic you can just draw stuff on a `<canvas>` on top of your video (and hopefully you'll also get back from Mars somehow).

Comment: Good to know ```canvas```. Will the graphics in the canvas be saved with video recording as well?

Comment: No, it won't be. Like the `<div>`, it's just an element.

Comment: But how. can anything like canvas be saved with video?

Comment: By my quick skim of videojs-record's code, it only records a https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream (i.e. the stuff you get from the webcam) - not sure if there's a way to hook in to add arbitrary content in there.

Comment: hmm. If it's not videojs-record, have you heard any other video recording plugin where we can hook a customized background to it? Thanks!